# How to show history with remote git repository only in JGit

Tags: jgit

I only want to run the `git log` command to get some commit info, and don't want to do it after cloning a remote reprository to local. Wonder if there is quick way for JGit here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All operations on a Git repository are local. In order to access the history of a repository, you must clone it first.

If you are only interested in the current state you may do a shallow clone to save some bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out by using new FileRepositoryBuilder().setGitDir() to t local repo.